# Вывод данных из БД по совпадению из итерации в цикле массива

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Добрый вечер друзья! Я в php новичок, но страстно мечтаю плотно освоить эту стезю. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в ситуации и понять как делаются такие вещи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока застрял вот на этом (Bad):

```
$mass_pro = [$composition];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = $con->query($sql);
foreach($result as $row) {
if (in_array($row['id'], $mass_pro)) {              
echo $row['name'];  
}
}
```

Но есть подозрение, что где то сбился с пути. Прошу помочь. Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем вообще так хранить данные о составе, извращение имхо... А если понадобится найти все блюда, содержащие Свинину? Почему бы не использовать промежуточную таблицу IdБлюда-IdПродукта. Да и категории тоже надо выносить отдельно (например, что будете делать, если захотите переименовать категорию?). В общем на лицо абсолютно неверная организация данных в базе.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Спасибо! Ситуация в том, что я пока ещё не очень разбираюсь в PDO и не знаю как по ходу выполнения кода выполнять пересечение данных из одной таблицы с другой, по этому, как временное решение использую данный вариант. Попробую конечно как Вы предложили, но это ещё больше запутает меня. Не могли бы Вы на основе Вашего варианта набросать код как это примерно будет работать?

Comment: @Incognito PDO вообще не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу. Не надо "пересекать" какие либо таблицы средствами PHP. Сначала надо сделать SQL-запрос, который выберет данные в нужном вам виде. А потом уже этот запрос выполнить и буквально вашим примером кода вывести на экран. Так что вам надо изучать SQL, а не PHP. Если сделать такую структуру как предлагает Ella, то запрос будет вида `select t1.name, t1.description, group_concat(t2.name) from t1,t2,t3 where t1.id=t2.blud_id and t3.id=t2.prod_id group by t1.name, t1.description`.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya все правильно, только не так резко. Это не извращение, а незнание. Ответ, рописывающий базовые понятия релационных БД на этом примере был бы весьма полезен для сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Такие вещи" ни в коем случае не хранятся в таком виде в базе. Такие таблицы строятся с помощью группировки. Например:

```
select id
      ,group_CONCAT(id_of_composition) as composition
from table 
group by type;
```

Это в том случае если вам нужно сгруппировать идентификаторы. В случае наименований будет использоваться та же функция, но запрос будет чуть сложнее.

---

Более сложный пример:

Имеются таблицы

```
composition (составляющие)
| id_comp | name   |
-------------------- 
|1        | молоко | 
|2        | мясо   | 
|3        | кофе   |
|4        | масло  |
|5        | хлеб   |

dish (блюда)
| id_dish | name               | 
--------------------------------
|1        | кофе с молоком     | 
|2        | бутерброд с мясом  | 
|3        | бутерброд с маслом | 

entry (вхождения)
| id_entry | id_dish | id_comp|
--------------------------------
|1         | 1       | 3      |
|2         | 1       | 1      |
|3         | 2       | 5      |
|4         | 2       | 2      |
|5         | 3       | 5      |
|6         | 3       | 2      |
```

Запрос:

```
Select d.name
       ,group_CONCAT(c.name) as composition

From composition c
     ,dish d
     ,entry e
Where d.id_comp = e.id_comp and e.id_dish = d.id_dish
Group by d.name,
```

Comment: Ну так автор как раз и спрашивает, как построить запрос, который будет "чуть сложнее"

Comment: @Ипатьев, я указал автору функцию для получения нескольких результатов в одной строке, что собственно и требовалось автору. Была бы в наличии полная схема, написал запрос чуть сложнее в ответе

Comment: и при этом используется запрос к единственной таблице без джойна. Если честно, то эта отписка куда больше годится для комментария, чем для ответа.

Comment: @Ипатьев в запросе специально не использовал сложные конструкции, для начинающего.